# XSLT Filter not working

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

My count is coming up ok, but when I filter further to just CODE=’A’ or ‘B’, I get ‘C’ as well for NODE GUID=”2”.

It looks fairly straight forward but I'm not sure what I’m doing wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

See XSLT for the XPATH expression.

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NODEs>
    <NODE GUID="2">
        <Name>Michael</Name>
        <Activities/>
    <NODEs>
        <NODE GUID="1">
            <Name>Larry</Name>
            <ParentNODE>2</ParentNODE>
            <Activities>
                <Activity GUID="A1">
                    <ActivityCodes>
                        <ActivityCode>
                            <CodeTypeName>CODE</CodeTypeName>
                            <CodeValue>A</CodeValue>
                        </ActivityCode>
                   </ActivityCodes>
               </Activity>
           </Activities>
       </NODE>
       <NODE GUID="2">
           <Name>Joe</Name>
           <ParentNODE>2</ParentNODE>
           <Activities>
              <Activity GUID="A2">
              <NODECode>2</NODECode>
              <ActivityCodes>
                  <ActivityCode>
                      <CodeTypeName>CODE</CodeTypeName>
                      <CodeValue>A</CodeValue>
                  </ActivityCode>
              </ActivityCodes>
          </Activity>
          <Activity GUID="A3">
              <NODECode>2</NODECode>
              <ActivityCodes>
                  <ActivityCode>
                      <CodeTypeName>CODE</CodeTypeName>
                      <CodeValue>C</CodeValue>
                  </ActivityCode>
              </ActivityCodes>
          </Activity>
          <Activity GUID="A4">
             <NODECode>2</NODECode>
             <ActivityCodes>
                 <ActivityCode>
                     <CodeTypeName>CODE</CodeTypeName>
                     <CodeValue>B</CodeValue>
                 </ActivityCode>
             </ActivityCodes>
         </Activity>
      </Activities>
    </NODE>
   </NODEs>
  </NODE>
 </NODEs>
```

This is relevant XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0"
    xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
    xmlns:PS="http://localhost"
    exclude-result-prefixes="saxon PS">

  <xsl:apply-templates select=".//Activity" mode="I_NODE">                
  </xsl:apply-templates>

  <xsl:template match="Activity" mode="I_NODE">
    <xsl:variable name="Code" select="ActivityCodes/ActivityCode[CodeTypeName = 'CODE']/CodeValue"/>  <!-- 'A'/'B' -->

    <xsl:if test="$Code = 'A' or $Code = 'B'">
      <NODE>
        <xsl:variable name="Count" select="count(preceding-sibling::*[$Code = 'A' or $Code = 'B'] ) +1"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$Count"/>    
      </NODE>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Current output:

```
<NODE>1</NODE>
<NODE>1</NODE>
<NODE>3</NODE>
```

Expected output:

```
<NODE>1</NODE>
<NODE>1</NODE>
<NODE>2</NODE>
```

Comment: What context are you using that XPath from? It's a little hard to debug with just the XPath. Also, that XPath is invalid. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It's from xslt: <xsl:variable name="Count" select="count(preceding-sibling::*[ActivityCodes/ActivityCode[CodeTypeName = 'CODE']/CodeValue = 'A'] or [ActivityCodes/ActivityCode[CodeTypeName = 'CODE']/CodeValue = 'B'] ) +1"/>

Comment: The XPath expression in question has a somewhat different form in the XSLT you edited in than did the standalone XPath expression about which you initially asked.  The new expression furthermore uses a variable `$SAPInternalCode` which is nowhere defined.  Perhaps you mean `$Code` there, but if so, then I don't think the expression means what you think it means.  In particular, it is not then analogous to the expression you originally posted.

Comment: Yes, I did mean $Code. I had tried many variations of the predicate and posted the incorrect one. Nevertheless, there should be a predicate that will work. The If statement processes only the A & B codes as can be evidenced in the output. 1 output for Larry and 2 outputs for Joe. The issue is with the count predicate where the count for Larry should be 2, but no matter what I try, it come up 3. There must be a logical explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XPath appears to be faulty:

> ```
> count(preceding-sibling::*[ActivityCodes/ActivityCode[CodeTypeName = 'CODE']/CodeValue = 'A'] or [ActivityCodes/ActivityCode[CodeTypeName = 'CODE']/CodeValue = 'B'] ) +1
> ```

it looks like you mean for the `or` condition to be inside a predicate instead of between two predicates:

```
count(preceding-sibling::*[ActivityCodes/ActivityCode[CodeTypeName = 'CODE']/CodeValue = 'A' or ActivityCodes/ActivityCode[CodeTypeName = 'CODE']/CodeValue = 'B'] ) +1
```

That will count all the preceding siblings of the context node that have a descendant `ActivityCodes/ActivityCode/CodeValue` where the `ActivityCode` has a `CodeTypeName` child with value `'CODE'` and the `CodeValue` has value `'B'`.  You should be able to express the same thing a little more compactly, though:

```
count(preceding-sibling::*[ActivityCodes/ActivityCode[CodeTypeName = 'CODE'][CodeValue = 'A' or CodeValue = 'B'] ) +1
```

Personally, I find the more compact version clearer, too.

Comment: This is strange. I tried both versions and in both cases I get a count of 3 for Node 2, so 'C' is still being counted.  I imagine for the compact version there shoud be a ']' just before the ')'.

Comment: I also tried putting the path in a variable, but still getting count of 3 for the NODE with name ‘Joe’:
<xsl:variable name="Code" select="ActivityCodes/ActivityCode[CodeTypeName = 'CODE']/CodeValue"/>
<xsl:variable name="Count" select="count(preceding-sibling::*[$Code = 'A' or $Code = 'B'] ) +1"/>

Comment: @jkoul, Do note that your expression has a `+1` at the end, which mine carries over.

Comment: Noted.  I have edited my post to include the relevant XSLT above. I still have no idea why @John Bollinger's two answers and the one in the XSLT above do not produce the correct output. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: @Jkoul, if I substitute the exact XPath expressions already suggested in this answer into your XSLT, as the expression for the value of the `$Count` variable, (and fix one or two minor but seemingly unrelated problems in it) then the resulting transform produces the output you say you want, not what you claim to get.

Comment: Your right, as it turns out it was a data issue, so frustrating. Thank you ever so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to count amount of all `ActivityCode` blocks where `CodeTypeName = 'CODE'` and `CodeValue = 'A'` and `+1` then use count as below:

```
count(//ActivityCode[CodeTypeName = 'CODE' and CodeValue = 'A']) + 1
```

Result:

```
3
```

But if you want to count amount of all `ActivityCode` blocks where `CodeTypeName = 'CODE'` and `CodeValue = 'A'` in `NODE` block where `GUID = '2'` and `+1` (as above) use as below:

```
count(/NODEs/NODE[@GUID = '2']/NODEs/NODE[@GUID = '2']//ActivityCode[CodeTypeName = 'CODE' and CodeValue = 'A']) + 1
```

Result:

```
2
```

Comment: Thanks @O.F. but there can be several nested levels of NODEs/NODE. My sample XML was a very small snippet of data.